# NavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener Not working

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, menuitem

I post this message because I realy search a solution but nothing works.
I try to get an interaction with the item in the menu on a Navigation Drawer Layout.
I work on Android Studio and I picked the base tamplate for Navigation Drawer that Android Studio makes.
Here is my code :

```
public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private NavigationView navView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        this.navView = navigationView;

        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawerLayout)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(this.navView, navController);

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(menuItem -> {
            int id=menuItem.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(menuItem,navController);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

I tried to put a `setNavigationItemSelectedListener` on my navigationView to get the menuItems that where clicked, plus I've put an Toast to make shure that it was well fonctionning but the Toast never appeared.

To be complete, here is my XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">


    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="@string/menu_home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="@string/menu_gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="@string/menu_slideshow" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_connexion"
        android:title="@string/connexion" />

</menu>
```

I also tried to put a Toast on `onOptionsItemSelected` and the Toast works perfectly, so I don't understant why the Toast on the menuItems don't work.

Here is my arborescence of XML directories.
[image]

And here is my XML file for the setting Toast:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Comment: So I created the same project and  copy and pasted your code and it works fine. I get a toast when I click "Settings" as well a when I click "Home". There must be something else happening, something else you have done has caused this.

Comment: I also tried to replace the Taost by a Log but always the same, nothing displyed

Comment: Yes because something else you have done has caused this. Create a brand new application, don't rename anything just add your `onOptionsItemSelected` method and `navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener` lines of code and you will see it works just fine mate

Comment: ok I try and tell you if it's working

Comment: Oh and change this line `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);` to `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);`

Comment: What does the "main" refer to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224784/discussion-between-tom-ribardiere-and-david-kroukamp).